# node.js on Raspberryp]Pi not showing any terminal output

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've installed node.js on my RaspberryPi running Raspbian using

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

it looks as though it has installed, I got no errors on installation, but when I check the version, I don't get any terminal output from `node -v` or `node --version`.

I wrote a simple js file just outputting test to the console, and when I run that from the command line with `node index.js`, I also don't get any output in the command line.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? is the Raspbian terminal in some way different from other platforms (I can't imagine it is).

I've also installed following the directions in this post (up to configuring the server) http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2013/03/raspberry-pi-and-nodejs-basic-setup/ and get the same result, no output in the console

Comment: nodejs package itself has npm, which may be interfere with your other installations. Remove and clean any nodejs/npm installation and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to re-create my raspbian image (not sure why), and after trying countless different ways of installing node, I ended up using this script https://github.com/midnightcodr/rpi_node_install, it took forever, but it worked in the end.

I've also more recently seen posts which say `sudo apt-get install node-js`, but didn't try that one myself.

Answer (score 4):

The debian packages for node.js usually don't provide the binary as `node` (`/usr/bin/node`) but rather as `nodejs` (`/usr/bin/nodejs`) due to possible naming conflict with another binary from another package.  (See also http://ypcs.fi/howto/2013/03/23/nodejs-debian/ for example) So you should call `nodejs -v` etc.

Alternatively/additionally, you can create a symbolic link with `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`. Useful expecially if you have to run shell script that expect node to be named `node`.

Comment: Thanks Miichi, I ended up having to re-install everything agot it working as per my answer here. I now get the version back just by calling node -v, which I prefer, as it is more consistent with all the other node documentation.